# 5-stars html-css redirecting to link

Tags: html, css

So I want to make a 5-stars rating system in html-css, when clicking on a star, It will redirect to a link and will rate an element.

HTML:

```html
<div class="star-rating">
    <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=1"></a>
        <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=2"></a>
            <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=3"></a>
                <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=4"></a>
                    <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=5"></a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.star-rating{
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.star{
    display: flex;
    color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.star a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.star::before{
    content: '★';
    color: inherit;
}

.star:hover{
    color: yellow;
}
```

What can I do to make a star click redirect to a link, while keeping the fact that the star the mouse hovers over changes color, as well as the stars before it?

(Sorry for bad English).

I tried to make the anchor elemnt `width = 1em` and the .star `margin-left = -1em` but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not a case for `div`s and `float`. Just use `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.star::before{
    content: '★';
    color: inherit;
}
```

Move that `★` *into* the link, so you got something to click on - change the selector to `.star a::before`

```
.star:hover{
    color: yellow;
}
```

And change that to modify the color of the *child* link of the hovered `.star`, but not also the rest of them in the nested `.star` elements inside, by making that `.star:hover > a`

```css
.star-rating{
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.star{
    display: flex;
}

.star a{
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.star a::before{
    content: '★';
    color: inherit;
}

.star:hover > a{
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-rating">
    <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=1"></a>
        <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=2"></a>
            <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=3"></a>
                <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=4"></a>
                    <div class="star"><a href="/rate?r=5"></a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more fix to make it as OP wants, the `color:gray` should be for `.star a` and not the div

Comment: @Randommm yeah, fair point, edited. And the `cursor: pointer;` on `.star` can also go then, assuming that was not explicitly overwritten for `a` elements elsewhere.